# MySQL - delete from table Y based on results of deletion from table X

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Let's say I have two tables:

```
tableA
-------
type   (varchar)
name   (varchar)

tableB
-------
name   (varchar)
...
```

I want to delete all records from `tableA` where `type='foo'`. I can do this as follows:

```
$STH=$DBH->prepare("DELETE FROM tableA WHERE type = :t");
$STH->bindParam(':t','foo');
try {
    $STH->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I then want to note the `name` field in each of the records that I deleted from `tableA` and use this to delete any records in `tableB` with those names. How can I do that?

I want something equivalent to `$DBH->lastInsertId();` except that it passes back all the `name` fields from the deleted records.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can join both tables and perform delete on them, eg

```
DELETE  a, b
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
          ON a.name = b.name
WHERE   a.type = 'foo'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22f21b/1)

Comment: Just discovered I actually want `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to include all records from `table1` which do not have corresponding records in `table2`. Glad to tip you over the 50K mark, too :)

Answer (score 2):

On top of JW's answer, if this is a permanent thing that you want to do (i.e. the data is denormalized) you can add a `CASCADE DELETE` to `tableB.name` that references `tableA.name`. This requires that you use a database engine that supports foreign keys (i.e. InnoDB)

Comment: Thanks for the `CASCADE DELETE` lead. I'll leave that until a day on which I feel braver :)

Comment: @nick Np. It's fairly straight forward in principle, however you need to ensure that you always want to delete both records. The one big downside (along with the trigger solution) is that this is "hidden" in terms of your code. I.e. you're pushing business logic into the database.

Comment: Yes, that's what I understood it involved. I'll leave it visible in the code for the time being. Makes me feel safer :)

Answer (score 1):

and  the last option, would be trigger usage, manual here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html but JW's answer is elegant and good solution for you